# amazonの価格取得

Tags: javascript, php, api

、amazonの個別商品ページのURL(例)http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4822242633
を使って、商品価格だけを抜き出す場合、いろいろとやり方はあると思いますが、皆さんならどのように実現されますでしょうか。
教えて頂けますと、幸いです。
※言語はPHPでお願いいたします。
※amazon apiはリクエスト制限があるので、amazon api以外でお願いいたします。
※商品価格とは以下のタグの部分です。

```html
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price offer-price a-text-normal">￥ 2,376</span>
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: amazonの規約違反だと思いますが、回答される方の参考までに、関連するメタへのリンク：  [http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1633/%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%81%AB%E6%84%8F%E5%9B%B3%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%8C%99%E5%8B%95%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%B1%E5%AE%B9%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B](ソフトウェアに意図しない挙動を行わせる質問は許容されるのか？)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4822242633");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$ret = $xml->xpath('//span[@class="a-size-medium a-color-price offer-price a-text-normal"]');
echo $ret[0];
?>
```

Xpathで抜き出すならこれだけでできます。

PHPでのスクレイピングはこのQiita記事が参考になります。
[sPHPネイティブのDOMによるスクレイピング入門 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/c0312271819baee09132)

Comment: 補足です。Amazonのような大規模なサイトの場合、製品によってパスが違ったりするため、完全一致のXpathを使うと運用が大変になる場合があります。そのため極力少ない条件で一致するよう工夫したほうがいい場合が多いです。
この場合だと
//span[contains(@class, "offer-price")]/text()
が適切かと思います。